# Getting Asterisk Dialplan user list on the android application

Tags: java, android, sip, asterisk, voip

I am developing a project in which Android client connects with Asterisk SIP server and can call to another SIP client connected with the same Asterisk SIP server. While doing so each time I have to manually enter the USER ID (which I mention in the SIP.conf file)  of the client whom I want to contact with. Is there any way such that I can retrieve the "Dialplan users list" from the Asterisk server onto my Android SIP client.
Please suggest me with any solution possible.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can get list on server via [AMI](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+API). But bad idea do that from client app. Better create server app which will check any info you need and provide api for your client(with restictions).

Looks like you are trying to re-invent [phone provision](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Phone+Provisioning+in+Asterisk).

Comment: Can you suggest how I should I do that? I want to obtain IP addresses of the clients connected to asterisk and later want to establish TCP connection between the clients for file transfer as I think its difficult to with asterisk.

Comment: I think you have hire skilled developer. You can get list of peers via "sip show peers " command on asterisk or in db if you use realtime sip with update turned on. But considering NAT that not mean you can use thoose ips to connect device.

Comment: No I am doing it on my own...let me know the way please

Answer (score 0):

You can send via ami [actions](http://the-asterisk-book.com/1.6/asterisk-manager-api.html)

```
  SIPpeers     system,all   List SIP peers (text format)
```

Comment: Shahrooz thank you! should I send this ami actions from the client?

Comment: @user2674903 you can connect to ami with socket on port:5038

Comment: @user2674903 you can also use ami over http https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Allow+Manager+Access+via+HTTP

Comment: shahrooz..I have tried AMI commands using Telnet but I am not getting how should I do that from the Android application?